# How to put a panel from different class on a frame without disposing off frame

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

I am doing a project of computer shop management where i have many frames and panels. I have a class named admin panel which contains the frame which further has some buttons i.e : home, about us, add product etc.
Now I want to launch a new panel inside the frame as the button ADD PRODUCT is clicked but the code for the panel should be from different class like a class named addProduct in the same package , How can i do that?

Here you can see all the buttons

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yGJYk.jpg]

I have been successful in launching a panel from different class on the same frame but the problem is that a new frame is launched and I don't wanna do that.

ADMIN PANEL CODE:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTabbedPane;

public class adminPanel implements ActionListener {

    public static final Font MY_FONT = new Font("Ubuntu Mono", Font.BOLD, 20);
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
    JButton admin = new JButton("Administrator Login");
    JButton employee = new JButton("Employee Login");
    Dimension screensize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
    ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\faroo\\Desktop\\car sales stock\\ComputerImage.jpg");
    Image scaledImage = image.getImage().getScaledInstance(screensize.width, screensize.height, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
    JLabel backgroundImage;

    JButton[] buttons = new JButton[10];

    String[] dropDown = new String[]{
        "Hi", "Hello"
    };
    JList list = new JList(dropDown);

    adminPanel() {
        //Frame
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLayout(null);
        frame.setSize(screensize.width, screensize.height);
        frame.setLocation((screensize.width / 2) - (frame.getWidth() / 2), (screensize.height) / 2 - (frame.getHeight() / 2));
        frame.setLayout(null);

        //IMAGE BACKGROUND
        image = new ImageIcon(scaledImage);
        backgroundImage = new JLabel(image);
        backgroundImage.setBounds(0, 0, screensize.width, screensize.height);
        
        //PANEL 1
        panel1.setBounds(screensize.width / 2 - 485, 120, 970, 42);
        panel1.setBackground(new Color(223, 223, 223));
        panel1.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEADING));

        //BUTTON: HOME + ABOUT US + ADD PRODUCT + REMOVE PRODUCT +SALES DETAILS +SAlES ORDER
        buttons[0] = new JButton("HOME");
        buttons[1] = new JButton("ABOUT US");
        buttons[2] = new JButton("ADD PRODUCT");
        buttons[3] = new JButton("REMOVE PRODUCT");
        buttons[4] = new JButton("SALES ORDER");
        buttons[5] = new JButton("SALES DETAILS");
        buttons[6] = new JButton("LOG OUT");

        for (int i = 0; i <= 6; i++) {
            buttons[i].setFont(MY_FONT);
            buttons[i].setFocusable(false);
            buttons[i].setBackground(new Color(61, 94, 148));
            buttons[i].setForeground(new Color(223, 223, 223));
            panel1.add(buttons[i]);
            buttons[i].addActionListener(this);
        } 
        frame.getContentPane().add(panel1);
        frame.getContentPane().add(backgroundImage);

        frame.setVisible(true);

    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        for (int i = 0; i <= 6; i++) {
            if (e.getSource() == buttons[i]) {
                for (int j = 0; j <= 6; j++) {
                    buttons[j].setBackground(new Color(61, 94, 148));
                }
                buttons[i].setBackground(new Color(69, 89, 119));
            }
        }
        if (e.getSource() == buttons[2]) {
            addProduct asd = new addProduct();
        }

    }
}
```

addProduct CLASS CODE:

```
package carsalessystem;

import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class addProduct extends adminPanel{

  
    
    addProduct(){
        JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();
        frame.dispose();
        panel2.setBackground(Color.darkGray);
        panel2.setBounds(panel1.getLocation().x,panel1.getLocation().y+42,970,800);
        frame.add(panel2);
        frame.add(backgroundImage);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        
    }
}
```

Comment: An application should only have a single JFrame. If you need popup child windows then you should use a `modal JDialog`. If you want the frame to be able to display different panels in the same area of the frame then you should be using a `Card Layout`. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use CardLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html)

Comment: Ok i got u, but what if i don't want to code all the panels in one class, rather in different classes and then show it in a single frame....?

Comment: What is the issue?. As long as the main class has a reference to the child panel you can use the CardLayout to swap panels based on the button that was clicked.

Comment: Ok thanks, do u have any code that could help me , I would be very thankful to you.

Comment: I gave you a link to the tutorial that contains working code. To understand the concept, modify the code from the tutorial to make the panels a separate class. That is create a `Card1Panel` class with the 3 buttons and create a `Card2Panel` class with the text field. All that will change in your code is that the two panels are in a separate class. Once you get that working, then you work on your real application.